# Calculating gradients of a certain layer in YAMNET

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gradient

I'm trying to get gradients value from 'layer14/pointwise_conv' layer of [YAMNET](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/audioset/yamnet).

To begin with, I just opened a [repository](https://github.com/SangwonSUH/yamnet_get_gradient/tree/master) so that you can easily see the exact same code that I'm struggling with.

YAMNET contains mel_spec feature extraction and framing within the structure of the tf_model.
(ex. for instance, audio file included in the project is 10-second long, and converted into 19-framed-mel_spec data while processing)
Therefore, I intended to get grads_val of each frame like,

```
y_c = yamnet.output[0][0, prediction.argmax()]
conv_output = yamnet.get_layer('layer14/pointwise_conv').output
grads = K.gradients(y_c, conv_output)[0]
gradient_function = K.function([yamnet.input], [conv_output, grads])

output, grads_val = gradient_function([INPUT_IMAGE])
```

but only the first frame was processed properly.

[image: Output]

How can I calculate the gradients of each frame?

Answer (score 1):

The published YAMNet was trained with raw TensorFlow, then "translated" to Keras to make it easier to use.  However, we're not Keras experts, and we're having some issues with the behavior.

You may be able to get the result you want by presenting frames to the classifier one at a time.  Each classifier output frame is based on 0.975 seconds of audio (15,600 samples of 16 kHz waveform), with successive frames based on successive chunks of audio; by default, the frames advance by 0.48 seconds (so 15,600-7,680 = 7,920 overlapping samples between successive frames).

If you manually chunk your input into overlapping blocks of 15,600 samples, then pass them to the network one at a time, your existing calculation of gradients may work.

There should be a simpler solution that works with the provided Keras machinery, but I don't know enough about it.